# Check if have invalid values in string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove empty values from a var to leave only valid values.

Example

```js
  var values = "teste,,teste1,teste2,,,,teste4"
```

Then output should be  "teste,teste1,teste2,teste4"

Comment: You should post what you have tried ir order to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this i prefer this regex method**

```js
let temp = "teste,,teste1,teste2,,,,teste4".replace(/,+/g,',');
console.log(temp);
```

**This too**

```js
let str = "teste,,teste1,teste2,,,,teste4".split(',').filter(e=>e).join(',')

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to turn it into an array, combine it with `filter` to remove empty values, and then `join` the string back together

```js
let r = "teste,,teste1,teste2,,,,teste4".split(",").filter(_=>(_)).join(",");
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split on the commas, then use filter:

```js
var values = "teste,,teste1,teste2,,,,teste4".split(',').filter(String)

console.log(values)

// Convert back to string
console.log(values.join(','))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the split() method the string by ",". This will return an array of strings, some of which are empty. Then iterate over the loop and get all the values different than "".